# Xamarin Forms Bind-able Picker - How to get selected item in ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am using Xamarin forms : 2.3.4.247
Prism Library : 6.3.0

The following is the code having Bind-able Picker ass in latest Xamarin Forms:
**VIEW**

Registered the (prism) behaviors in my view as under

> xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms"

Picker also showing the data of **CountryCodes** which is a list of type *PickerItem*

```
       <Picker  ItemsSource="{Binding CountryCodes}" Title="Select Country"  ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}">
            <Picker.Behaviors>
                <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" Command="{Binding ItemTappedCommand}" EventArgsParameterPath="Item" />
            </Picker.Behaviors>
        </Picker>
```

in respective  view model I've defined the command as under

```
public DelegateCommand<PickerItem> ItemTappedCommand { get; }
```

and In constructor:

```
ItemTappedCommand = new DelegateCommand<PickerItem>(OnCountryPickerTapCommandExecuted);
```

The  delegated function is as under:

```
private void OnCountryPickerTapCommandExecuted(PickerItem item)
{
    SelectedCountryCode = item.Code;//some property I want it to assign
}
```

The issue is the picker is binding properly, however when selecting/changing selection nothing happen:

Am I missing something, in prism?

Comment: have you tried to make your binding twoway?

Comment: @Diceble - Yup tried that as well, nothing changes, few times I get An unhandled exception occurred. However I can not debug it on which lines this is happening. Something is to do with 'EventArgsParameterPath' thats what I could figure out.

Comment: If I remove the EventArgsParameterPath="Item" parameter from code, I can  dubug, and OnCountryPickerTapCommandExecuted(PickerItem Item) is executed, however as obvious the item is returned null. so this seems that Parameter path has some issues which I can not resolve, help please guys.

Comment: not sure why however my LogCat shows NullReferenceException:   as seen ---------------->Info 2411 MonoDroid System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Prism.Behaviors.EventToCommandBehavior.OnEventRaised (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs eventArgs) [0x00054] in <7a32c28f35024e719a93e31b4d1e3d2a>:0 
.... <OnClick>b__0 (System.Object s, Android.Content.DialogClickEventArgs e) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\PickerRenderer.cs:103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need an event to command behavior. You can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44221341/how-to-bind-datepicker-and-picker-in-xamarin/44222758#44222758) on how to work with pickers. The example isn't using Prism but how it works is the exact same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PickerDemo" 
             x:Class="PickerDemo.PickerDemoPage">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:PickerDemoPageViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <StackLayout Padding="10,20">
        <!-- Picker with explicitly set values in XAML -->
        <Picker SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <Picker.Items>
                <x:String>Item 1</x:String>
                <x:String>Item 2</x:String>
            </Picker.Items>
        </Picker>
        <Label Text="{Binding SelectedItem,StringFormat='You Selected: {0}'}" />

        <!-- Picker with Dynamically set values -->
        <Picker ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding AnotherItem}" />
        <Label Text="{Binding AnotherItem,StringFormat='You picked: {0}'}" />

        <!-- Date Picker using a custom display format -->
        <DatePicker Date="{Binding SomeDate}" Format="MMMM dd, yyyy" />
        <Label Text="{Binding SomeDate,StringFormat='{0:dd MMMM, yyyy}'}" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

EDIT:

There is no SeletedItemChanged event, only a SelectedItemIndexChanged event, which is kind of pointless. In Prism 6.3 you can however do something like the following:

```
public class FooBar : BindableBase
{
    private INavigationService _navigationService { get; }

    public FooBar(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }

    private string _foo;
    public string Foo
    {
        get { return _foo; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _foo, value, OnFooChanged);}
    }

    private async void OnFooChanged() => 
        await _navigationService.NavigateAsync("SomePage", new NavigationParameters() { { "foo", Foo } });
}
```

Comment: Actually I need that selected item in next view, Prism allows passing navigation parameters (and so selected item), the above example only shows same view binding, which is simple,  can you suggest further?

Comment: BTW whats Fody weaver needed for? Just to bind PropertyChanged as in Prism? does Fody provides same functions.

Comment: I believe the update above should answer your question there. The sample uses Fody PropertyChanged to cut down on the code. You can use it with BindableBase or any base ViewModel class. You can read more about it on my [blog post](https://dansiegel.net/post/2017/03/16/writing-cleaner-more-concise-code-with-fody). Note that the latest version of Fody PropertyChanged actually deprecates the need to use the `InjectPropertyChanged` attribute as it will pick it up automatically if you added `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Brian Lagunas, pointed it in XF forums here (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/277628#Comment_277628) as well as the above answer is also meeting the criteria... I also figured out that my code had a incorrect property of Type<string> instead of  Type<T> which also blotted the functionality. so I'll still thank you all and mark this as an answer.